# Page does not move to top update panel inside user control

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, scrolltop

I have a user control on a ASP.NET page. Inside the user control there is a update panel. The page is a little lengthy and has Validation Summary control at the top.

The Submit button is at the bottom of the page. When I click the submit and when client side validation fails (on requiredfieldvalidators), the page DOES NOT move to the top where the Validation Summary control shows the messages. It just moves till the user control which is in the middle of the page.

I tried settings MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" on the aspx page, but that didn't work.

How can I make it so when client-side validation fails, it moves to the top of the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the validation fails try to focus a control that is near the validation summary, maybe that work. ie. txtName.Focus(). If the validation is happening in the client side, try to do some js to detect when the summary appears....

Comment: Thanks mtzaldo. Validaiton is happening on the client side (EnableClientScipt="true"). I tried using jquery scrollTop() and that doesn't seem to work. It goes till the user control and not to the top of the page. Also tried javascript window.scrollTop(0,0).function ValidatePage() { Page_ClientValidate(); if (!Page_IsValid) {
                $("#lblDealNumber").scrollTop();
//$('#lblDealNumber').animate({ scrollTop: $('#lblDealNumber').offset().top + 1000}, 200);
//window.scrollTo(0, 0);  //scroll to top of the page }}                                                           Any other ideas?

Comment: @KiranD, Did you get solution for this?